# How to Improve Select Query Performance For Large Data in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently,I am working on one php project. for my project extension,i needed to add more data in mysql database.but,i had to add datas in only one particular table and the datas are added.now,that table size is 610.1 MB and number of rows is 34,91,534.one more thing 22 distinct record is in that table,one distinct record is having 17,00,000 of data and one more is having 8,00,000 of data.
   After that i have been trying to run SELECT statement it is taking more time(6.890 sec) to execute.in that table possible number of columns is having index.even though it is taking more time.
   I tried two things for fast retrieval process 
                      1.stored procedure with possible table column index. 
                      2.partitions.
   Again,both also took more time to execute SELECT query against some distinct record which is having more number of rows.any one can you please suggest me better alternative for my problem or let me know, if i did any mistake earlier which i had tried.

Comment: You will need to provide more information such as table structures etc. for people to be able to help you effectively

Comment: You should also consider the possibility of using caching, for not hitting the database as your queries are taking too long, of course the database caching is not the best answer in all of the cases, specifically when your data changes a lot.

Comment: Cache Cache and Cache

Comment: "number of rows is 34,91,534 ... 22 distinct record(s)" What is a record if not a row?
"one distinct record is having 17,00,000 of data" - 17 Mio of What? Bytes? Cols?
And what is your select looking like?

Comment: ok,i explain brief about that table, distinct record means let consider country column, it is having 22 distinct value. one of the value is canada, out of 30 lakh of total data 17,00,000 rows is having canada in country column.

Comment: the size is 152.7MB.                         SQL: select distinct state from from zip where country='canada'   my select statement looking like this above i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When working with a large amount of rows like you do, you should be careful of heavy complex nested select statements. With each iteration of nested selects it uses more resources to get to the results you want.

If you are using something like: 
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table
WHERE condition

and it is still taking long to execute even if you have indexes and partitions going then it might be physical resources.

Tune your structure and then tune your code.

Hope this helps.